# Compound Queries not working even with index

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to query a collection with 2 fields. One I am using >= and the other is used for orderBy

I have created a composite index with these 2 fields but I get this error:

```
Exception 'Invalid query. You have a where filter with an inequality (lessThan, lessThanOrEqual, greaterThan, or greaterThanOrEqual) on field 'expiresAt' and so you must also use 'expiresAt' as your first queryOrderedBy field, but your first queryOrderedBy is currently on field 'sharedAt' instead.' was thrown while invoking collectionGet on target RNFirebaseFirestore with params (
    "[DEFAULT]",
    "users/je601IzZ33VZGYg7iNeTEfOgsis1/canvas",
        (
                {
            fieldPath =             {
                string = expiresAt;
                type = string;
            };
            operator = "GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL";
            value =             {
                type = number;
                value = 1563621170;
            };
        }
    ),
        (
                {
            direction = DESCENDING;
            fieldPath =             {
                string = sharedAt;
                type = string;
            };
        }
    ),
        {
    },
    "<null>",
    198,
    199
)
```

my query:

```
firestore().collection(`users/[id]/canvas`)
      .where('expiresAt', '>=', Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000))
      .orderBy('sharedAt', 'desc')
```

So, it's telling me I need to have expiresAt as the first orderBy. so:

```
firestore().collection(`users/[id]/canvas`)
      .where('expiresAt', '>=', Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000))
      .orderBy('expiresAt', 'desc')
      .orderBy('sharedAt', 'desc')
```

When I do that, I get the error that the system is not in the correct state to perform the query.

I've tried different combinations to get this to work.

Some info: expiresAt is the time the item in the collection will no longer be visible to the user. SharedAt is the time the item was first added to the user's list.

edit: Schema is simple. Users have a subcollection 'canvas' which has items and the only fields that are concerned here are timestamps:

```
title: String,
description: String,
sharedAt: Number,
expiresAt: Number
```

Comment: Show us your database schema.

Comment: The first error (about changing the first orderBy) is expected.  The second error (not in the correct state) is not.  Can you add the full error text?  Also, can you confirm the index is fully constructed (by looking at your indexes in the Firebase Console)?

Comment: @MichaelLehenbauer I can confirm indexes are created with sharedAt and expiresAt. The rest of the error was the stack trace... so not much use here.

Comment: Having the exact error text makes it more feasible for me to look up the error and figure out what might have caused it. AFAIK "system is not in the correct state to perform the query" is not an error that Firestore ever emits.